# Zapier Python code generate Unique Id without hyphens

Tags: python, zapier

the code (Pyton) that I currently have generates an id with hyphens (ex: `djdfj1-sdfd-3f`) I would like the code to generate this unique ID, but without the hyphen (ex: `djdfj1sdfd3f`).
Does ayone know the code to leave without a hyphen? 
Thank you.

Actual code:

```py
import uuid

uuid_length = 17

return { 
    'unique_id': str(uuid.uuid4())[:uuid_length]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`'unique_id': str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')[:uuid_length]`

should remove your hyphens